# Why can't I access the files under the app internal path (xxxx.app/Contents/MacOS/) after packaging on Qt mac?

Tags: macos, qt

I saved the file to the xxxx.app/Contents/MacOS/ path via qt, and after using macdeployqt to package the file, I double-clicked on the xxxx.app file to open the app, and could not read and access the file.

However, when I open the application using the terminal in the xxxx.app/Contents/MacOS/xxxx path, everything works fine.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, in the mac directly write the name can not find the current path, you must add before the path

QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()